# How to compare 2 datatables without any loops and key relationships in c# or linq

Tags: c#, linq

What is the best way to compare two `DataTables`.  If I have 2 `Datatables` with same data, if I change any value in datatable 2, while comparing I don't want to check row by row, count and memory with datatable 1.

Comment: Show us your code so that we can understand your question better.

Comment: Seems impossible -- what do you mean "without any loops"?

Comment: This sounds like it may be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - perhaps explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Do the tables have the same structure or you only want to compare some fields, can you detail more?

Comment: Issue solved.thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you get 2 DataTable object and want to check for differences between them then you'd probably must use loop.
If you want to react on change in object then you can use RowChanged event.
If you'd like to get changes since last read then use GetChanges() method.

Answer (score 0):

A [.Except()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.8) might be useful here. It produces a set difference of two sequences.

Comment: .Except() uses a loop internally so this does not answer the question.

Comment: i tried except .it will give the changed rows  rows result.if both datatabels same still you will get all the rows.so you cannot get both tables are same or not by using except.

Comment: @Hogan Uses loop internally no problem.but i don't want to create loop funtion using forech and for loop etc.

Comment: we have to use intersect here below i have added my code 

var temp = dt1.AsEnumerable().Intersect(dt2.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default);

if(temp.count != dt1.count)
{
   //Logic
}

This is the solution

Answer (score 0):

Two datatables - `mtbl` for master data, `dtbl` for detail data or the new data you're comparing to.

```
var differences = dtbl.AsEnumerable().Except(mtbl.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default);
            return differences.Any() ? differences.CopyToDataTable() : new DataTable();
return differences.Any() ? differences.CopyToDataTable() : new DataTable();
```